# Item not found after dropping captcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I add captcha to the site. After successfully filling out the form appears captcha. When it is completed, the form is sent, and the captcha is discarded. But when resetting in the console, an error occurs:

`recaptcha__en.js:184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at Z (recaptcha__en.js:184)
    at MC.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:492)`

In HTML:

`<div id="captcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY }}" data-size="invisible"></div>`

Render captcha:

`captcha = grecaptcha.render(document.querySelector('#captcha'), {
            sitekey: $('#captcha').data('sitekey'),
            size: 'invisible',
            callback: window.myFunction)
};`

Reset after send

`grecaptcha.reset(captcha);`

What can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: What does "when resetting in the console" mean?

Comment: When I send the form, I drop the captcha and the chrome debug console shows an error message.

Comment: Is your captcha div `<div id="captcha"...` still present on the page when you call `grecaptcha.reset(captcha)`?

Comment: Yes, present. The captcha block does not disappear from the page.

Comment: have you solved this?